# Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, repository, setup-project

I am getting the above error message when I try and create a simple maven project. I have exhausted the previous suggestions, e.g. Window > Preferences > Maven > Archetypes > Add Remote Catalog... and adding this as the catalog file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

When I click verify it says this is empty.

I have also tried deleting the maven repository in the .m2 directory with no reward.

My complete error is this:

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\USER_ID\.m2\repository)
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\USER_ID\.m2\repository)
```

The maven-metadata.xml file is in the correct place (I think) but I'm not entirely sure if it is the right file contents, what should go in this file?

I have also tried deleting and changing the settings.xml file in terms of both content and location, again with this repeated, infuriating message.

Comment: Adding a mirror in the %MAVEN_HOME%\conf\settings.xml file worked for me. Here are some examples: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.meta/repository-metadata.xml .

Comment: I've also added `<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>`

Answer (score 4):

After some research on the same issue I have found that one of the solutions found was to follow these steps:

Open Window > Preferences
Open Maven > Archetypes

Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the following:

- Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
- Description: maven catalog

Hope this is of some use to you.

Comment: I tired this. Instead eclipse showed a blank list of maven artifacts